# Verifying if Mummy Finance on Fantom is a Fork of GMX: Identical On-Chain Code

Tags: solidity, fantom, arbitrum, project-fork

Hello StackExchange community,

I am interested in investing in a protocol called Mummy Finance, which is built on the Fantom network. The developers of Mummy Finance claim that their project is a fork of GMX. Before I invest, I would like to verify if the on-chain code is indeed identical across the many contracts involved in both projects. I am looking for a reliable method to compare the two protocols and ensure that Mummy Finance truly is a fork of GMX.

for One the github repo's might differ from what is on chain, and two i am a engineer, but i dont have any solidity expertise so manually going through the contracts is a big pain..

How would you verify that a project is indeed a fork ?

Comment: I would ask that they provide a security audit of the deployed contracts.